# Hiding an element with animaion in SVG file

Tags: svg

```
<g id="Closed_Eyes">
    <path d="Closed eye data" />
</g>
<g id="Open_Eyes">
    <animate dur="0" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <path d="Open eye data" />
</g>
```

I have an SVG face and like to animate blinking eyes. The animate does not work because the duration is zero, but if I change zero to some time, it is animate opacity. I should not be using opacity but I must use hiding on the open_Eyes object. The idea is that if we hide open_Eyes, the background close_Eyes shows and then shows. This will give if eyes are blinking. Kindly guide me on how we can animate blinking with animate.

I tried with opacity, but it changes the opacity with time. That is wrong. Perhaps I need two animations. First, hide the open_Eyes object and then show it.

Answer (score 0):

Using dur="0" in animate won't work. If you just want to toggle the object you could either use a really small duration value (wouldn't recommend it though) or use the set tag like this:

```
<animate dur="0.001s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

or this

```
<set attributeName="visibility" to="hidden" fill="freeze" />
```

You also dont need the repeatCount if you just want it to stay invisible or when using no duration. Use fill="freeze" instead, as seen in the second code example i made, to keep the state after the animation finished.

Comment: This works <animate id="op" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="0.5s" begin="0.5s;op.end+3s" />